# How to operate multiple ZeroMQ Socket Types In The Same Process?

Tags: c++, zeromq, blocking

I am looking to use ZeroMQ to facilitate IPC in my embedded systems application, however, I'm not able to find many examples on using multiple 0MQ socket types in the same process.

For example, say I have a process called "**`antenna_mon`**" that monitors an antenna. I want to be able to send messages to this process and get responses back - a classic **`REQ-REP`** pattern. However, I also have a "**`cm`**" process, that publishes configuration changes to subscribers. I want **`antenna_mon`** to *also* subscribe to antenna configuration changes - **`PUB-SUB`**.

I found [this example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:msreader) of reading from multiple sockets in the same process, but it seems sub optimal, because now you no longer block waiting for messages, you inefficiently check for messages constantly and go back to sleep.

**Has anyone encountered this problem before?** Am I just thinking about it wrong? Maybe I should have two threads - one for CM changes, one for **`REQ-REP`** servicing?

I would love any insights or examples of solving this type of problem.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. In my opinion, it depends on your need. Or I pose questions to you: what is the logical relation between `cm` and `antenna_mon`? Are they all blocking or non-blocking? Are they access the shared memory? Anyway, I think your question is not about ZeroMQ, it is just about your need. So, analysis your need, design the structure, then code. For me, how to operate multiple socket is a question about structure, and ZeroMQ is another question about code.

Comment: @Yuhui
CM is a publisher that notifies subscribers when a configuration parameter has changed. So antenna_mon is interested in configuration change notifications. However, I also want to query antenna_mon about his state to get statistics out of him. Is ZeroMQ suited for this job? If so, how do I do it? All of the examples in the guide have each process only doing one thing, but in real life I want antenna_mon to do multiple things (be a subscriber to config changes, but also be a server for queries)

Comment: You answered your own question in the comments below.  zmq_poll() does exactly what you are looking for.  You can also register timers in the poller so you can "wake" the thread periodically for other work (not triggered by an incoming message).

Comment: @colini Thanks, polling turned out to be what I wanted to do. I needed to be more patient and get further in the guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Welcome to the very nature of distributed computing!

Yes, there are new perspectives one has to solve, once assembling a Project for a multi-agent domain, where more than one process works and communicates with it's respective peers ad-hoc.

A knowledge base, acquired from a soft Real-Time System or embedded systems design experience will help a lot here. If none such available, some similarities might be also chosen from GUI design, where a centerpiece is something like a lightweight **`.mainloop()`** scheduler, and most of the hard-work is embedded into round-robin polled GUI-devices and internal-state changes or external MMI-events are marshalled into event-triggered handlers.

ZeroMQ infrastructure gives one all the tools needed for such non-blocking, controllably poll-able ( scaleable, variable or adaptively ad-hoc adjustable poll-timeouts, not to overcome the given, design defined, round-trip duration of the controller **`.mainloop()`** ) and transport-agnostic, asynchronously operated, message dispatcher ( with thread-mapped performance scaling & priority tuning ).

### What else one may need?

Well, just imagination and a lot of self-discipline to adhere the Zero-Copy, Zero-Sharing and Zero-Blocking design maxims.

The rest is in your hands.

Many "academic" examples may seem trivial and simplified, so as to illustrate just the currently discussed, or a feature demonstrated in some narrow perspective.
[image]

Not so in the real-life situations.

As an example, my distributed ML-engine uses a tandem of several **`PUSH/PULL`** pipelines for moving state data updates transfers and prediction forcasts + another **`PUSH/PULL`** for remote keyboard + a reversed **`.bind()/.connect()`** on **`PUB/SUB`** for easy broadcasting of distributed agents' telemetry to a remote centrally operated syslog and some additional **`PAIR/PAIR`** pipes, as processing requires.

( <sub>**nota bene:** one shall always bear in mind, that robust and error-resilient systems ought avoid to use a default REQ/REP Scaleable Formal Communication Pattern, as there is non-zero probability of [**falling** the pairwise-stepped `REQ/REP` dual-FSA **into an unsalvageable deadlock**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D%20deadlock). [Do not hesitate to **read more** about this smart tool.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D)</sub> )

Comment: I guess my question is - in that diagram with the server that uses PUB/ROUTER/PULL - how is that being actually implemented? Does the server have 3 threads (one for handling PUB socket, one for handling ROUTER, one for handling PULL) or is it just using NOBLOCK option in all three and checking them in a loop?

Comment: Actually, I just came across this: http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:mspoller - I think I'll try polling for now

Comment: Guess the best next step is to read the great Pieter Hintjens' book **"Code Connected: Vol.1"** Definitely worth your time and tears & sweat, indeed. My code never goes without NOBLOCK, always maps sockets onto threads, with different I/O priorities, and if going into threads, may well benefit with Zero-Copy PAIR/PAIR or PUSH/PULL over inproc:// transport class ( effectively a super-fast shared blocks of memory ). You will, sure, love it.

Comment: Because of the **mainloop** time-step budget, I have so far preferred to rather have a specialised poller for each purpose, where I can warrant both the maximum round-trip time and the minimum duration, a proportionally wighted poll-delay spends on each channel per one **".mainloop()"**-round-trip loop ( a guarranteed time-discriminated attention share per cycle for each messaging & signalling I/O-channel ( + the .Context() relative priority mapping on a pool of ZeroMQ service I/O-threads ) ).